# jQuery Infinite Scroll is not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using jQuery infinite scroll. Its working perfect on desktop but when I try it on my mobile device its not working. I am not sure but I guess there is something in the code which is not allowing it to run on the mobile devices. For 1st Ajax call of data (the code before `$(window).scroll(function(){`) is being fetched properly. However, the code after `$(window).scroll(function(){` is not being executed. What can be the issue? Please help me fix it. Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
var ajax_arry=[];
var ajax_index =0;
var sctp = 100;
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#loading').show();
  $.ajax({
    url:"processes/loadTimeline.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:"actionfunction=showData&page=1",
    cache: false,
      success: function(response){
      $('#loading').hide();
      $('#demoajax').html(response);
    }
  });
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var height = $('#demoajax').height();
    var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(ajax_arry.length>0){
      $('#loading').hide();
      for(var i=0;i<ajax_arry.length;i++){
        ajax_arry[i].abort();
      }
    }
    var page = $('#demoajax').find('.nextpage').val();
    var isload = $('#demoajax').find('.isload').val();

    if (($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) && isload=='true'){
      $('#loading').show();
      setTimeout(function(){
        var ajaxreq = $.ajax({
          url:"processes/loadTimeline.php",
          type:"POST",
          data:"actionfunction=showData&page="+page,
          cache: false,
          success: function(response){
            $('#demoajax').find('.nextpage').remove();
            $('#demoajax').find('.isload').remove();
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#demoajax').append(response);
          }
        });
      }, 1000);
      ajax_arry[ajax_index++]= ajaxreq;
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```